# Punti cardinali relativi

Tags: word-usage

Vi trovate davanti un tavolo con un piatto e un pezzo di pane. Io vi dico: "Il pezzo di pane si trova a nord del piatto". Come interpretate questa affermazione? Il pezzo di pane si trova nella zona del tavolo che si estende oltre il piatto nella direzione della vostra linea visiva, o si trova invece in direzione del Nord terrestre relativamente al centro del piatto?

In generale vorrei sapere se i punti cardinali possono essere usati relativamente ad altri punti di riferimento che non sono la Terra stessa. In che situazioni, se ne esistono, posso usare usare "Nord" e "davanti, di fronte" intercambiabilmente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Nord" significa soltanto "nord", cioè in direzione del polo Nord (semmai il dubbio può essere se parliamo di quello geografico o magnetico). I punti cardinali sono stati inventati, per così dire, *proprio* per evitare l'ambiguità di indicazioni come "sopra", "davanti", "a destra": visto da me? da te? dalla sorgente del fiume (come quando si parla della riva destra o sinistra)?

Comment: Capisco, grazie!

Comment: Si potrebbe usare l'espressione "Il pezzo di pane si trova a ore dodici del (rispetto al) piatto"

Comment: Giusto, @RiccardoDeContardi, quello è un buon metodo se entrambi gli interlocutori sono orientati nello stesso modo.